# Delete a Module in Outlook Project

Tags: vba, outlook, vbe

Can I delete an Outlook VBA Module?

I have tried the below code:

```
Dim vbMod As Object

Set vbMod = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
vbMod.Remove VBComponent:=vbMod.Item("Module2")
```

But getting an error:

> 438 Error, Object doesn't support this property or method

Can this be done with Outlook VBA and are there any References to be included?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

You will need to add a reference to *Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3*.

```
Public Sub DeleteModule(ByVal ModuleName As String)
    On Error GoTo Trap

    Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
    Dim objProject As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim objComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
    Set objProject = VBAEditor.ActiveVBProject

    For Each objComponent In objProject.VBComponents
        If objComponent.Name = ModuleName Then
            objComponent.Collection.Remove objComponent
        End If
    Next

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

To test it:

```
Sub Test()
    DeleteModule "ModuleName"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your answer is no, we can't delete or even access programmatically the VBIDE; it is correct that you can add reference to Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3, but to no avail.

If you try this at Word or Excel, this is the output:

[image]

But, when you try this at Outlook, VBE is not exposed:

[image]

[Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-delete-outlook-modules-and-forms-using-vba/d31285c2-985f-4b76-a1eb-c24338b7e66d) is a confirmation. Maybe in older Outlook versions, less safer, you could do that, but at least since [Outlook 2002](https://bettersolutions.com/outlook/add-ins/vba-code.htm), it is not possible.